# Issue with configuring Selenium Grid with appium in android studio

Tags: android, json, appium, selenium-grid

I am automating android application using appium tool and android studio IDE. I have created 2 JSON files for each device. I have started selenium hub and running appium server on different ports. But I don't know how should I define `capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Should read from the JSON file");` in my test code?
My JSON files contains (device name and port number changed incessant JSON file):
`{
"capabilities":
[
{
"platformName": "Android",
"platformVersion": "4.4",
"maxInstances": 1,
"device": "5200cf1a4df52100"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"nodeTimeout":120,
"port":4728,
"hubPort":4444,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"url":"http://localhost:4728/wd/hub",
"hub": "http://localhost:4444/grid/register",
"hubHost":"localhost",
"nodePolling":2000,
"registerCycle":10000,
"register":true,
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":30000,
"maxSession":1
}
}`

Selenium grid logs are -
`SBA53@DEVML0204666:~/Downloads$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub
15:27:01.945 INFO - Launching a selenium grid server
2015-03-10 15:27:03.674:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2015-03-10 15:27:03.757:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2015-03-10 15:27:03.775:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444
15:28:50.119 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{app=/Users/SBA53/Test-release/Rel1_683/android-skybet/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk, appPackage=com.skybet.app.skybet, appActivity=MainActivity, orientation=LANDSCAPE, appium-version=1.0, noReset=true, platformVersion=4.4, platformName=Android, deviceName= }]
15:28:50.120 INFO - Available nodes: [host :http://0.0.0.0:4728]
15:28:50.120 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node host :http://0.0.0.0:4728
15:28:50.121 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {platformVersion=4.4, platformName=Android, maxInstances=1, device=5200cf1a4df52100}`

Answer (score 0):

`deviceName` is not needed, see below...

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "iPhone",
          "version":"8.2",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "platform":"MAC"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url": "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 4723,
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "localhost"
  }
}
```